# Defend against HTTP fingerprinting

Tags: defense, fingerprinting

I'm looking for ways to defend against common fingerprinting techniques used by hackers to identify what kind of setup my website is running on.

I understand this is a complicated topic, and every setup probably has it's own solutions. I'm new to security so I don't even know where to start really.

To help narrow out the answers I'm running nginx 1.2.1 and PHP5-fpm on a debian machine. It's self hosted so there's no limit to what I can change.

I'm looking for solutions/resources that a casual developer like myself can understand and implement to make it as difficult as possible to determine my setup. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm not trying to hide my response headers, that's done. I want to add some protection against fingerprinting software that analyzes my website behavior to determine my setup.

**More clarification:** The type of answer I'm looking for should be concerning:

- *Faking server/machine behaviour to confuse the fingerprints*
- *Detecting attempts to fingerprint the system*
- *Counter-measures*

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question, but —

I wouldn't dedicate any substantial time to preventing this. It doesn't add any security.

Your general setup (nginx+PHP) is so common that any determined attacker would try to exploit it anyway — and nobody will simply give up if they don't see a "Server: nginx" header. You will simply waste (potentially lots of) time making sure that — for example — all `filename.php` URLs are hidden from end-users.

Comment: I'm working on a project where fingerprinting is not only a possibility, but sooner or later it WILL happen (most likely very early). And I need to slow them down as much as I can. I know security by obscurity isn't fool-proof, but it adds an extra hurdle for the attackers to overcome.

Comment: -1 Information disclosure vulnerabilities are a low risk threat that can lead to more serious problems when combined with other vulenrablites.

Comment: @hustlerinc: What I mean is — server software fingerprinting is not an attack.

Comment: It's a step to decide what attack to use, say it's easy to find out my HTTP server version, and php version. Then even a script kiddie can google possible security holes to use. See where I'm going? I'm defending against much more sofisticated attackers, so sooner or later they will get in no doubt about it, I just want to slow them down.

Comment: @hustlerinc — Yes, I definitely understand the theoretical concern. I'm simply saying that if you've hidden the ultra-verbose "Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.5.0 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8y" server header, then additional steps are very often a waste of time. If you're using a software version that has known exploits (that a script kiddie can find/use), any automated attack will destroy you anyway.

Comment: The headers are hidden, my question is concerning software used to analyze server behavior to try to determine my setup. The way this is done is by comparing traffic to fingerprints in the software database. You've misunderstood the question.

Comment: @hustlerinc I haven't misunderstood it — I get that you want to completely prevent anyone from determining what exact setup you're using. If we assume that this will be done in an automated way anyway, the attacker can simply try all known exploits no matter what.

Comment: @hustlerinc Additionally — I'm not saying you should never pursue this avenue, but that it's mostly an unneccesary time-sink. For example, if you choose to build nginx from source simply to avoid having the server name header, you'll likely cause more maintenance/security problems in the future.

Comment: @JoelL When the attackers are the FBI/NSA/IRS nothing is unnecessary. :)

Comment: @hustlerinc: You're far better off using a known secure setup than wasting a lot of time on security through obscurity. Joel is correct: There are basically 4 possible webservers, maybe 6 or 7 languages, and 4 likely backend databases. A brute force approach will figure out your system in short order.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy Time is not an issue, this is what I want to do. Let's stick to the topic.

Comment: @hustlerinc: The answer is given. You have to alter the source of your chosen webserver to make it behave the way you want it to. And once you do that, you will have to re-compile it every time you need to patch it. And, inevitably, you will end up with a server that is not patched, and far more vulnerable than one that announces it's name.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy Clearly you don't know what you're talking about. For example to prevent banner grabbing the book Hacking Exposed states: "To prevent this Network Administrators should be sure to restrict access to services on their networks to appropriate networks and be sure to shut down unused or unnecessary services running on network hosts." There is not one universal solution to this. I'm asking for possible solutions to common fingerprinting techniques. And as you say, it is far more vurnerable than using the official release. I'm not trying to hide completely, that's close to impossible.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy It was a copy-paste excerpt (from Wikipedia) just to prove my point. I haven't read the book. What I'm trying to say is you're not helping at all. Hence everything you write is unnecessary, "duuuh security by obscurity!!" comment's are everywhere, and we've all read them. I will not rely on this solution alone, it is just there to confuse. You get it? Now give a constructive answer or don't bother. There ARE measures to take, problem is the paper's on the subject are too technical for me to understand. When you have a project that could land you in jail you'll understand.

Comment: @hustlerinc: The point he's making in the book is that you shouldn't have unnecessary services running exposed where anyone can exploit them. That's good advice, and completely irrelevant in this case. All public-facing webservers are exposed. That's what they're for. The way to secure them is to keep them PATCHED, and not to run poorly secured software on them. Whatever php you're planning to run, that's your vulnerability, as long as you keep your webserver patched.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy Not irrelevant, since I'm using that solution (modified) already. My database only stores 59 minutes of information at best, and another machine is getting the rows by connecting to it. So even if the "main" machine is compromised at most 59 minutes worth of information is found. You just don't have the full picture, the backup machine is outgoing only, since noone knows about it. It takes alot of bricks to build a fortress.

Comment: @hustlerinc If you're really facing state-level threats, then you really are wasting your time. You won't "confuse" a three-letter agency for more than ten minutes by, for example, sending `Server: apache` from your nginx web server. Since you've already spent more than ten minutes arguing about this, I figure you're way behind.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's a cat and mouse game. In this case the mouse is just watching them step in the traps and deploying new ones. The traps are a metaphor for my servers. The way I've set it up keeps me safe.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> make it as difficult as possible to determine my setup

since you have no restrictions on what you can do on your server, your best bet is to dig into nginx source code and make your own build.

Comment: Good point, but I'm not a good developer and this would be really overkill (and I would most likely screw it up).

Comment: It seems your concern is so huge about fingerprinting the server, this is why it is the only option you have, AFAIK